# Using MouseListeners to paint?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, events, graphics

I am trying to make a program with a simple grid of rectangles where, if the user clicks on a rectangle, it is filled black. The problem I am having is that my mouseClicked method cannot access my paintComponent method, so I get an error.

Here is relevant code:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    super.paintComponent(g2);
    g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    for(Rectangle2D rect : squares) {
        g2.draw(rect);
    }
}

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    if((e.getX()>RECT_WIDTH && e.getX()<RECT_WIDTH+(game.getSize()-1)*BOX_DIM) && (e.getY()>RECT_HEIGHT && e.getY()<RECT_HEIGHT+(game.getSize()-1)*BOX_DIM)) {
        Point2D point = new Point2D.Double(e.getX(), e.getY());
        Rectangle2D rect = findRect(point);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fill(rect);
        repaint();
    }

}

public Rectangle2D findRect(Point2D p) {
    for(Rectangle2D rect : squares) {
        if(rect.contains(p)) {
            return rect;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

"squares" is an arraylist of rectangle2Ds. The error is in the mouseClicked method on 'g' because eclipse cannot find g. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your List object you need to store an object that contains two pieces of information:

1. The `Rectangle`
2. the `Color` of the `Rectangle`

When you click on the `Rectangle` you iterate through the `List` to find the `Rectangle` that was clicked and then you update the `Color` property of that `Rectangle` and invoke repaint().

You will also need to change the painting code to set the Color of the Rectangle before you invoke the draw() method.

Check out the `DrawOnComponent` example found in [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It shows how to create the custom object to store two properties and how to paint this object in the paintComponent() method.